# Rust features which allow the optimizer to change the program's result?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization

In some languages, optimization is allowed to change the program execution result. For example,

- C++11 has the concept of "copy-elision" which allows the optimizer to ignore the copy constructor (and its side-effects) in some circumstances.
- Swift has the concept of "imprecise lifetimes" which allows the optimizer to release objects at any time after last usage before the end of lexical scope.

In both cases, optimizations are not guaranteed to happen, therefore the program execution result can be significantly different based on the optimizer implementations (e.g. debug vs. release build)

Copying can be skipped, object can die while a reference is alive. The only way to deal with these behaviors is by being defensive and making your program work correctly regardless if the optimizations happen or not. If you don't know about the existence of this behavior, it's impossible to write correct programs with the tools.

This is different from "random operations" which are written by the programmer to produce random results intentionally. These behaviors are (1) done by optimizer and (2) can randomize execution result regardless of programmer intention. This is done by the language designer's intention for better performance. A sort of trade-off between performance and predictability.

**Does Rust have (or consider) any of this kind of behavior?** Any optimization that is allowed to change program execution result for better performance. If it has any, what is the behavior and why is it allowed?

I know the term "execution result" could be vague, but I don't know a proper term for this. I'm sorry for that.

I'd like to collect every potential case here, so everyone can be aware of them and be prepared for them. Please post any case as an answer (or comment) if you think your case produces different results.

---

I think all arguable cases are worth to mention. Because someone can be helped a lot by reading the case details.

Comment: In `debug` compilations integer overflows panic, while in `release` mode they do not. Would that qualify as an answer?

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer because proving a negative is always difficult, but as far as I know, there is no such behavior in Rust. `Copy` literally means bitwise-copy, `Clone` isn't that special in the compiler's eye, move also always means bitwise-copy, etc.

Comment: @rodrigo Yes I think that's one of the case as `release` mode program can continue so can produce different result.

Comment: I don't think there is one, I think rust core team would considered it as a bug. https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-not-considered-unsafe.html#exiting-without-calling-destructors https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html

Comment: I'd disagree that the integer overflow case is related because it's **not the optimizer** making that decision/change. You can enable panic-on-overflow separately from any optimizer step. It just happens to be under the umbrella of "debug" vs "release".

Comment: Would you consider `-DNDEBUG` to be an "optimization"?

Comment: @trentcl It seems like an expression of programmer's intention rather than an optimizer. Isn't it? Does program produce consistent result for each case of with or without the flag?

Answer (score 4):

If you restrict yourself to *safe* Rust code, the optimizer shouldn't change the program result. Of course there are some optimizations that can be observable due to their very nature. For example removing unused variables can mean your code overflows the stack without optimizations, while everything will fit on the stack when compiled with optimizations. Or your code may just be too slow to ever finish when compiled without optimizations, which is also an observable difference. And with unsafe code triggering undefined behaviour anything can happen, including the optimizer changing the outcome of your code.

There are, however, a few cases where program execution can change depending on whether you are compiling in debug mode or in release mode:

- Integer overflow will result in a panic in debug build, while integers wrap around according to the two's complement representation in release mode – see [RFC 650](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0560-integer-overflow.md) for details. This behaviour can be controlled with the [`-C overflow-checks` codegen option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#overflow-checks), so you can disable overflow checks in debug mode or enable them in release mode if you want to.
- The [`debug_assert!()` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.debug_assert.html) defines assertions that are only executed in debug mode. There's again a manual override using the [`-C debug-assertions` codegen option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#debug-assertions).
- Your code can check whether debug assertions are enabled using the [`debug-assertions` configuration option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#debug_assertions)

These are all related to debug assertions in some way, but this list is not exhaustive. You can probably also inspect the environment to determine whether the code is compiled in debug or release mode, and change the behaviour based on this.

None of these examples really fall into the same category as your examples in the original question. Safe Rust code should generally behave the same regardless of whether you compile in debug mode or release mode.

Answer (score -2):

There are far fewer foot-guns in Rust when compared to C++. In general, they revolve around `unsafe`, raw pointers and lifetimes derived from them or any form of undefined behavior, which is really undefined in Rust as well. However, if your code compiles (and, if in doubt, passes `cargo miri test`), you most likely won't see surprising behavior.

Two examples that come to mind which can be surprising:

The lifetime of a MutexGuard; the example comes from [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html):

```
while let Ok(job) = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv() {
    job();
}
```

One might think/hope that the `Mutex` on the `receiver` is released once a job has been acquired and `job()` executes while other threads can receive jobs. However, due to the way value-expressions in place-expressions contexts work in conjunction with temporary lifetimes (the `MutexGuard` needs an anonymous lifetime referencing `receiver`), the `MutexGuard` is held for the entirety of the `while`-block. This means only one thread will ever execute jobs.

If you do

```
loop {
    let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
    job();
}
```

this will allow multiple threads to run in parallel. It's not obvious why this is.

Multiple times there have been questions regarding `const`. There is no guarantee by the compiler if a `const` actually exists only once (as an optimization) or is instantiated wherever it is used. The second case is the way one should think about `const`, there is no guarantee that this is what the compiler does, though. So this can happen:

```
const EXAMPLE: Option<i32> = Some(42);
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(EXAMPLE.take(), Some(42));
    assert_eq!(EXAMPLE, Some(42)); // Where did this come from?
}
```

Comment: All of your given examples are well-defined irregardless of applied optimizations. For example, types implementing `Drop` are dropped when the owner goes out of scope; the drop order is stable.